# Getting Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND when using node-soap

Tags: node.js, web-services, soap

I have a SOAP web service which I need to read from a node.js application and decided to use [vpulim/node-soap](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap)

The web service works when I use a SOAP client but I can't get it to work on a node.js application. I'm getting the below error message:

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND www.xxxxxxx.intra.com.mt www.xxxxxxx.intra.gov.mt:9011
    at errnoException (dns.js:26:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:77:26)
```

The strange part is that the actual URL is www.xxxxxx.com.mt without the intra part. I don't get why it shows differently here.

Below is the code I'm using.

```
var url = 'https://www.xxxxxxxx.gov.mt/wsRPS.asmx?WSDL';    

  soap.createClient(url, function(err, client){
     //client.addSoapHeader(soapHeader);
    //
    var args = {
      from: "2016-03-01T11:00:00",
      to: "2016-03-03T11:00:00"
    };

    client.GetInformation(args, function(err, result){
     if(err){
       throw err;
     }
     console.log(result);
    });
  });
```

Any ideas on what's going on? Thank you

Comment: one year old qn.  Did you find a solution?

Comment: nope, no solution yet - I ended up doing this in PHP instead... I didn't find any luck using NodeJS for soap (wasn't really built for it either)... I'll be happy to try any recommended solutions.

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide the client endpoint :

```
const url = 'https://www.xxxxxxxx.gov.mt/wsRPS.asmx';

soap.createClient(`${url}?wsdl`, (err, client) => {

    // here
    client.setEndpoint(url);

    const args = {
      from: "2016-03-01T11:00:00",
      to: "2016-03-03T11:00:00"
    };

    client.GetInformation(args, (err, result) => {
        if(err){
           throw err;
        }
        console.log(result);
    });

});
```

Comment: I get a similar error indicating getaddrinfo.  Your solution won't work because the value of "client" is undefined.  So, cannot perform undefined.setEndpoint(..)

Comment: You saved my day, i was gotting this error:
```
{ Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND guianeett guianeett:443
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:67:26)
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'guianeett',
  host: 'guianeett',
  port: 443 }
```